# Laravel Auth hidden redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Install new Laravel 5.4 project.

Run `php artisan make:auth`.

Go to http://localhost:8000/home (without being logged in).

I get redirected to http://localhost:8000/login

This redirect seems like magic. This is the route for home:

```
|| GET|HEAD |home||App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index|web,auth|
```

We never get to the `index()` method because the `auth` middleware takes 
over. I open the `auth` middleware file `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php` and there's no mention of the `/login` redirect.

Where is the redirect from `/home` to `/login` defined?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/search?q=%2Flogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file and you'll see `Exception handler` for unauthenticated users:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

P.S. redirect to `home` you can see in `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` file.

UPD1: redirect to home after login/register you can set in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` and `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`.
It looks like

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```